# sql select multiple rows based on conditions of two or more columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select multiple rows based on 3 columns matching particular criteria.  For a single search I do the following:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users_to_users 
WHERE user_id = '1' AND contact_user_id = '9' AND contact_blocked = 1
```

I would like to submit a set of values to return multiple rows.

so my values would be as such:

('1', '9', 1), ('2, '9', 1),('3', '9', 1) etc...

And return user_id's for the rows which match.  In essence I'm trying to see which users have blocked user '9' so that I could then add only the users that are not blocked to the next statement.

Being very unfamiliar with SQL what I thought might work was the following:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users_to_users
WHERE (user_id, contact_user_id, contact_blocked) VALUES (...)
```

But unable to do that.  Is there any way to select multiple rows based on matching conditions for multiple columns?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to use tuples with `in`?  If so, this works:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users_to_users 
WHERE (user_id, contact_user_id, contact_blocked) in ( (1, 9, 1), (2, 9, 1), (3, 9, 1) )
```

There may be other ways, however, to accomplish your ultimate goal.

Comment: I tried that but the error was operand must contain 3 columns.  Not sure what that means.

Comment: sorry disregard that.  I wasn't enclosing in the outer brackets.  silly.  thank you.